# Complete Statistic in Gamma distribution

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, inference, sufficient-statistics, complete-statistics

Let we have $n$ independent and identical random variables from gamma distribution with parameters $2$ and $\theta$, ie $G(2,\theta)$ where $n$ is greater than or equal to $2$. Check whether the following are sufficient and complete:

1. $\overline{X}$
2. $\overline{X}^2+3$
3. $(X_1,\sum_{i=2}^{n} X_i)$
4. $(X_1, \overline{X})$

I think all of them will be sufficient since gamma distribution belongs to exponential family. In the Gamma distribution, $\sum X_{i}$ is complete and any function of this will also be complete. Hence, first two options are complete and sufficient. I have doubt in the completeness of third and fourth options. I know, they will be sufficient as contains the whole information of samples.

Comment: This looks like textbook work. Include `self-study` tag if that is the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, $\bar{X}$ is sufficient because you can write the joint density as
$$
f(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = g[\bar{x},\theta]h(x_1,\ldots,x_n).
$$

To see if $(X_1, \sum_{i=2}^n X_i)$ is sufficient, can you write the joint density as 
$$
\tilde{g}[(X_1, \sum_{i=2}^n X_i),\theta]h(x_1,\ldots,x_n)?
$$

Regarding your other question proving completeness, try using linearity of the expectation operator. Is there some linear combination of the two statistics that has mean $0$, but isn't $0$ with probability $1$?

Comment: Yes, we can write the joint density in the way you specified. So, this means this Statistic will be sufficient. Am I right?

Comment: One more thing about Completeness. We know that $\overline{X}$ is complete for this distribution, then what is intuition behind the non completeness of the fourth estimator.

Comment: @RAHUlJHa  yep, that's right! Regarding the completeness thing, see my edit.

Comment: *Hint:* consider $X_1/\bar{X}_n$. Does it depend on $\theta$?

Comment: @Taylor $X_{1}-\overline{X}$ is having mean $0$. So, what this implies?. Sorry, I am having tough time understanding the Completeness.

Comment: @RAHUlJHa completeness means that for ALL functions of $X_1, \bar{X}$, if the mean is $0$, then that function has to be $0$ nonrandomly. Not complete means that there exists at least one function that if the mean is $0$, then the function isn't $0$ nonrandomly (it can be zero some places, but it's not zero with probability $1$).

Comment: Ok, so that means the above Statistics $(X_1,\bar{X})$ is not complete since $E(X_1-\bar{X})=0$ does not implies that $P(X_1-\bar{X}=0)$ doesn't equal to $1$. Have I used correct phrases?